# Is there a way to download biometric picture?

Tags: passports, russian-citizens, biometric-passports

I was very impressed by the equipment and photo processing done for the biometric passports at a Russian consulate (they take your photo right at the consulate, in a special room with a special setup).

The resulting photo is supposed to be stored within the chip of the passport itself.  Is there a way to get to it?  Or is there perhaps a way to get it from some central passport-application web-site of some sort, or any other source?

I would like to potentially acquire a copy of the photo to use for visa applications, for example.

Comment: What did the consulate say when you asked them?

Comment: How much programming do you want to do?

Comment: Just go to a photo shop and get new pictures. The need for "some" technical knowledge (and the passports security measures complicating everything) aside, the card reader hardware alone will probably cost more than all photos you´ll ever need. (And no, I doubt the consulate will do this for you)

Comment: frankly, i was most surprised by how clear and vivid my iris and a bit of щетина has appeared on the picture; although russian passports issued through consulates currently only have the photograph as the only biometric parameter that'll be embedded into the passport, the resolution and quality of optics and post-processing seem quite stellar

Comment: @deviantfan, which photo shop do you recommend?  I recall that last time I was recommended Walgreens or some such circa 2005 or 2006 or so, they had the attendant use the cheapest 150 USD camera (probably a 20 to 70 USD one in 2015 terms), and held it directly in their arms, all whilst the person were to stand next to some made-up screen; charging like 15$ for such passport photo; needless to say, a photo with an 2014 iPhone would look better that such professional services

Comment: @cnst I´m afraid I can´t recommend anything outside of central Europe, because I never needed to buy new photos elsewhere. But apparently, the situation here is much better than where you live (regarding price, quality etc.), so maybe I should take back that the hardware is more expensive than all photos together.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're trying to solve a non-existing problem as the old joke goes: "Через жопу".

The simplest way to get at the information on the chip is by using an app for your [NFC capable Android phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase&hl=en).  But if you really want to have a picture in electronic format just take a picture and use Photoshop to enhance it.  It will be much simpler then pulling it from your passport.

Besides most countries want a recent photo when applying for visas for which you can again use your [Android phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handyapps.passportphoto&hl=en)

Comment: If someone plans to make his own passport photos, read http://www.ruscon.org/forms/photospecs.htm etc. first.

Comment: Always a good idea.